# Using the contents of a file as a perl argument

Tags: linux, perl

I am trying to do the followng

```
perl something.pl -t happiness=LONGSTRING
```

where the LONGSTRING is very long (150,000 chars).  It was long enough to get the following message: "OSError: [Errno 7] Argument list too long"

I figured instead there would be a way to redirect the output of a file. I have not succeeded in doing so however.

What I am looking to do is something along the lines of:

```
perl something.pl -t happiness=<<<FILE.txt
```

where FILE.txt contains a bunch of text.  I have struggled in that the < or <<< is treated literally by the perl script and I am actually pushing '=<<

Comment: Why don't you just let the argument indicate that you want to read from a file?

Comment: If the contents of the file is bigger than the command line can accept, you can't pass the contents of the file as a command line argument.  So, you have to work around it.  One way is to pass the file name (and an argument to tell the command to read the file); another is to redirect the file to a known file descriptor (0 or standard input is the commonest one, but not necessarily the best — and you might need an argument to tell the script to process it specially).  But that's about it — if it is too big, you are hosed unless you can increase the limit, but it'll just be a new, bigger limit.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a limitation of Perl, but the OS/C library.

You could try increasing the limit, see [here for more info](http://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/argmax/).

Assuming you are using a modern Linux kernel, the limit is `stack size / 4`, to increase stack size, try `ulimit -s`*`number`* where *`number`* is the new stack size limit.

Answer (score 1):

```
perl something.pl -t happiness FILE.txt
```

Your first argument would be happiness (assuming this could be another word, otherwise just assign it inside something.pl) and then read FILE.txt separately, either one line at a time, or slurp the whole thing (though probably not recommended for 150k+ characters) and then process as you would normally.

The idea behind redirecting of output becomes moot when you have access to the source of the script -- people redirect output from things like GNU tools (ie 'df -h') because they can't (easily) edit the tool's source code to do their bidding.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could try something along the lines of this (Only for *nix):

```
perl something.pl -t happiness="`cat FILE.txt`"
```

This basically turns the contents of `FILE.txt` into a string which the command line can pass to your Perl script. I would not recommend doing it this way, and as others have suggested you should provide a file name and use that to read the file from within the script

Comment: Won't work as the resulting string is still too long